# How to duplicate a transform and then disable the original transform and keep the clone?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Cinemachine;

public class MyOtherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public bool go = false;

    private bool once = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (go && once == false)
        {
            GameObject newobj = Instantiate(transform.gameObject) as GameObject;
            newobj.transform.localPosition = transform.localPosition;
            transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            
            once = true;
        }
     }
}
```

Even if I'm using the `once` flag bool to make sure it will Instantiate only once, for some reason it's Instantiating nonstop cloning all the time.

Also, the cloned objects are have `activeSelf == false`, not the transform itself.

I want to make some kind of replacement between the transform this script is attached to and a clone of the transform. I want to use this to simulate smooth unparenting of the transform.

Doing just:

```
transform.parent = null;
```

is ugly, so I want to make the unparenting to be smooth, slow, and much more natural than just setting it to null. So instead of unparenting it, I thought it would be good to clone it at the right time and position.

This script is triggered by an event in my animation to mark the time I it to unparent:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DropObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MyOtherScript myotherscript;

    public void DropEvent()
    {
        myotherscript.go = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Even if I'm using the `once` flag bool to make sure it will Instantiate once for some reason it's Instantiating nonstop cloning all the time

This becomes obvious if you think about it for a moment.

1. Your original object (which has `go == true` and `once == false`) instantiates a clone of itself.

   This clones the *whole* object, including the `MyOtherScript` component with all its variables (including `go == true` and `once == false`)

   Your original object then sets its own `once = true` (but not the clone's) and turns itself off.
2. Now your cloned object gets *its* `Update()` called. Since it was spawned with an exact copy of the variables in your original (`go == true` and `once == false`), it proceeds to clone itself, then turn itself off.
3. Now the clone of the clone gets *its* `Update()` called...

etc.

> the cloned object/s [have] SetActive false and not the transform itself.

[Check the API documentation for the `Transform` component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html). `SetActive()` is not there. A `Transform` component does not have an active or inactive state.

Now look at your code:

```
transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

You *do not* tell the `Transform` to become inactive. You tell ask the `Transform` "Hey, what `GameObject` are you attached to?", and then you take its reply and tell *that `GameObject`* to become inactive.

> I want to make some kind of replacement between the transform this script is attached to and a clone of the transform

> I want to simulate smooth unparenting the transform.
>
> doing just :
>
> ```
> transform.parent = null;
> ```
>
> is ugly, so I want to make the unparenting to be smooth, [slow, and] much more natural

It is not clear to me what this even means, but I'm fairly confident that whatever it is you want to do, the way you have chosen is not an effective route to that goal.

I would recommend asking a new question. Take a step back from this code and try to describe the current situation in your game. Explain what player-observable behaviour you want, and ask how to achieve that behaviour. In particular, explain what specific unwanted outcomes arise from `transform.parent = null` - we need to understand clearly what problem we are solving to be able to offer an effective solution.